# The elementary theory of finite commutative rings

Tags: logic, model-theory, computability, decidability

I have wondered the decidability of elementary theory of finite commutative rings. Since we know that the elementary theory of finite fields is decidable shown by J.Ax ([The Elementary Theory of Finite Fields](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970573?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents),1968) but I cannot found the  results of finite commutative rings.

The most related article is [Elementary theory of a finitely generated commutative ring](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=mzm&paperid=5651&option_lang=eng) 
 shown by G.A.Noskov which says that the elementary theory of a finitely generated commutative ring is undecidable. However, this paper is about a single finitely generated commutative ring rather than a class of finite commutative rings.

So is the elementary theory of finite commutative rings decidable or undecidable?

Any comments or answers are welcomed. Thank you!